# How do I maintain any changes in the screen after pulling to refresh

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have forms, EditText, upvote count, etc that I can manipulate in a screen. How do I maintain any changes applied after pulling the screen to refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep the information in objects in the activity and populate the screen elements from there.